# Windows Server 2008 R2 Task Scheduler: Task does not repeat

Tags: batch-file, task, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

i have created a task with the Task Scheduler on my Windows 2008 R2 Sever.
It opens a **.bat file**. This bat has no errors and works fine.
If I start the task (i.e. by clicking on run) it executes the bat file. 
From now it should repeat **every x minutes** (currently set to 1 minute) but it does not.
I tried a lot and changed almost every property but it still **does not repeat executing my bat file**.

I have read different questions and answers but nothing worked.

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!
Björn

Comment: Have you set the duration field to `Indefinitely` in the task scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the error was about the "begin"-property of the trigger. It was set to "When task is created/modified". 
I changed it to a one time event. 
Things work fine now.